# Why table view is getting slow after implementing rating stars in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to implement rating stars by using kDRATING VIEW .i have used following code in cellForRowAtIndexpath method but it causes my app to become slower.
If it try to allocate and initialise this in viewdidload method then it when i scroll up and down ,the stars fluctuates . please help in this regard

```
  self.rating = [[KDRatingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60,20)];

  [self.rating rateKDRatingView:2.80 outOf:3.0];

  [cell.rating addSubview:self.rating ];
  return cell;
```

Comment: This is not helpful. Post all of your code in the cellForRowAtIndexpath

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to look into UITableViewCell reuse because when you scroll a UITableViewCell out of the screen it will call cellForRowAtIndexPath again to remake this cell when it is back in view and that can cause flickering and memory consumption.

You are adding the `KDRatingView` to the `rating` view on the cell so I guess you have a custom cell, so why not instead have the `KDRatingView` inside the custom cell and just update its value when you need to.

Try this solution with some cell reuse:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RatingCell";
    RatingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        // initialisation code
        cell = [RatingCell new];
    }
    // setting code
    [cell setRatingViewValue:2.8 outOf:3.0];
}
```

That way it only creates the cell once, so it won't slow down your app. Then each time the cell would have been recreated it just updates the cells rating (and anything else you need to set) instead.

Then you just need to implement the `setRatingViewValue:outOf:` method in your custom cell to update the `KDRatingView` that you need to have added and positioned in your custom cell upon initialisation.